# Conditional method calling by abusing ternary wrapped in if statement?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Recently I was doing a code review and came across this guy:

```
if(!sharePermission.isExpired() ? activePermissions.add(sharePermission) : expiredPermissions.add(sharePermission));
```

Basically using a ternary expression to call methods that return a boolean value and wrapping it in an `if(...)` statement to satisfy the requirement of being a standalone statement. Is this more or less valid than

```
if(!sharePermission.isExpired())
   activePermissions.add(sharePermission); 
else 
   expiredPermissions.add(sharePermission);
```

if you really need to condense your code to one line? Is any sort of extra space allocated for the value returned from the ternary expression when wrapped in the `if(...)` ?

I'm not a fan of either of them, just curious.

Comment: "Is this more or less valid than " It's certainly more bizarre. I'd have to read this a few times to make sure I understood what was happening.

Comment: I saw the comment you removed about `(sharePermission.isExpired() ? activePermissions : expiredPermissions).add(sharePermission);` and thought that was neat!  I would agree that the item I posted feels like an antipattern in a team environment.  Yours was a bit more elegant.

Comment: I don't particularly like that, so I removed it; I'd prefer `List<Permission> list = isExpired() ? expired : active; list.add(sharePermission);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no assignment happening, only an evaluation of a `boolean` condition. No extra memory is allocated for the result of the evaluation.

Using a ternary *expression* to emulate a ternary *statement*, however, is grossly unorthodox. It is going to reduce readability of your code, without bringing any additional benefit. Hence, using a plain `if` with an `else` is a better alternative.

Note that if `activePermissions` and `expiredPermissions` are of the same type, you can use a ternary expression to decide between the targets of the `add` call, as follows:

```
(sharePermission.isExpired() ? expiredPermissions : activePermissions).add(sharePermission);
```

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Nesting the conditional into an `if` is unnecessary, if all you want is side effects.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz That's a requirement for using them in a ternary operator.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Unrelated, but an `if` statement is *not* a "loop".

Answer (score 5):

It's an abuse of the `if` statement to do that, never mind the conditional expression.

It would be cleaner to write either a full `if` statement, or to use the conditional operator to select a list to add to:

```
List<Permission> list = isExpired() ? expiredPermission : activePermission;
list.add(sharePermission);
```

Answer (score 0):

The ternary equivalent for the `if..else` that you are looking for is something like -

```
(!sharePermission.isExpired() ? activePermissions : expiredPermissions).add(sharePermission); // no if here
```

is equivalent to

```
if(!sharePermission.isExpired()) {
    activePermissions.add(sharePermission); 
}
else {
    expiredPermissions.add(sharePermission);
}
```

Comment: But this is later evaluated to e.g. `if(activePermissions.add(sharePermission))`.

Comment: "The ternary equivalent for the if..else that you are looking for is something like" But it's not like that: you can't use the conditional operator as a statement expression.

Comment: Right, but that ternary doesn't compile as it isn't a statement.  Hence why the original was wrapped in an if _statement_.